# Install Redmine using ROR error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to install redmine in my localhost. I installed `Railsintaller` then i dowload svn code from `redmine`. I found steps to install redmine in localhost in the below  link `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ethtaYKdl9g`.

I got following error in the middle of installation. I am new to this environment.

Kindly check the below screen shoot and help to fix this.[image]

```
UPDATED MY QUESTION


C:\redmine>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rak
e/rdoctask.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/task.rb:30: warning: already ini
tialized constant Task
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Gem::SyckDefaultKey

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Please cut-and-paste instead of using a screenshot next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine requires Rails 2.3.14, and by the looks of it you've installed Rails 3.1.1.

You must install Rails 2.3.14 using this command:

```
gem install rails -v 2.3.14
```

Comment: Thanks, installed version 2.3.14 , now i am getting some issue.i updated my question. kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second issue, the `uninitialized constant Gem::SyckDefaultKey`error has been fixed in http://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/250. So you might want to update your package manager:

```
gem update --system
```

Before launching again your command.